# How do I acquire the serialized URL from HttpResponseMessage?

Tags: c#, url, .net-core, httpresponse, dotnet-httpclient

Is there a way to acquire the fully serialized URL address from a response?

Given the request below, I'd like to acquire the following string: `http://192.168.0.72:8080/manufacturer` if possible. This in fact is the URL that is sent to the server - but it's not what I'm able to extract.

This example is limited in scope as it does not demonstrate usage of *query parameters*, but usage of `BaseAddress` does mean that the Uri fed into `GetAsync` *will not always be* the actual URL sent to the server. Many things can manipulate it on it's way.

For example, if I was to pass in the query parameters `{"search": "test", "locale": "en-US"}` into the request, I'd hope to get `https://192.168.0.72:8080/manufacturer?search=test&locale=en-US`.

```cs
public static HttpClient InitializeHttpClient() {
    var client = new HttpClient();

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://192.168.0.72:8080/");
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(
        "User-Agent", "My App Name"
    );

    return client;
}
```

```cs
private static readonly HttpClient Client = Helpers.InitializeHttpClient();
```

```cs
HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.GetAsync("manufacturer");
Stream content = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
string url = response?.RequestMessage.RequestUri.ToString(); // "manufacturer"
```

For reference, I am on DotNet 6.0 running Xamarin Forms, building on Android.

Comment: You can't unless the server returns the info in the response.

Comment: Typically, you'd construct an `HttpRequestMessage` and then inspect the `RequestUri`. I have no idea what you're doing here however or how this client is being created or the querystring applied.

Comment: Can't you use `SendAsync()` instead, so when you build the `HttpRequestMessage` and set its [Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestmessage.content), you can read the full URI built from its `RequestUri`.

Comment: @Jimi How is the `HttpRequestMessage` being built beforehand any different from it being built automatically by `HttpClient.GetAsync`? The above code demonstrates access to `HttpResponseMessage.RequestMessage`, which appears to be precisely what you're referring to.

Comment: @DavidL I don't understand. The above code demonstrates precisely how the `HttpClient` instance is being created. There is no querystring example being applied in this example, but there are methods for applying `Dictionary<string, string>` as query parameters. In that instance, the original request URI used would look completely different from the URL actually being requested at runtime,.

Comment: Because I've interpreted this as: *see what the HttpRequestMessage is set to before it's sent, then compare with what the HttpResponseMessage contains when the method returns*.

Comment: While I would prefer to access this URL before the message is sent, either would be nice.